# Make my own indicator

Tags: indicator

I have a [script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397551/script-to-notify-me-when-something-happens-on-a-shared-directorycreate-modify) that notify me when some thing is modified on a directory.

I need to make indicator that takes over the notifications instead of pop up at my screen. I want the notifications to be displayed using this indicator.

So basically the question is devided into two parts:

1. How to make my own indicator?
2. How to redirect the notifications to be displayed on the indicator?

Using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by an indicator.

Comment: @GabrielF They are the stuffs found in the right top corner of Ubuntu such as sound indicator and chat .... Those are called indicators

Comment: Oh, sorry... I probably should have googled. Now, I believe you'll need to write a small application to do what you need. Do you have experience with any programming language? If you do, the official documentation should probably be enough to help you: http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/. If you don't, I can try to help you, but only after I got home.

Comment: @GabrielF I have a little bit knowledge of programming but a help of others is much better

Comment: I looked at the script. I'm not sure you need an indicator, I think you just don't want that clickable pop-up. Won't you be happy with a solution using ubuntu's notification system, like [this](http://pastebin.com/2PxfUiba) ?